# Django: Set default widget in model definition

Tags: django, widget

Is it possible to set a custom widget for a model in the model definition?

For example, having a model ModelA referencing to the model ModelB, I would like that a modelForm of ModelA renderes the reference field to ModelB automatically with a custom widget defined by ModelB.

The use case behind is the creation of a reusable app, where the reusable app should provide the form field widget for developers using the app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it possible to set a custom widget for a model in the model definition?

Yes, if you override the field: [Specifying the form field for a model field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#specifying-the-form-field-for-a-model-field).

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising.

Comment: The quality of this answer would improve immensely if it outlined an example rather than farming out to a link.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, based on [formfield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#specifying-the-form-field-for-a-model-field) proposed in earlier answer:

```py
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['widget'] = CurrencyWidget
        return super().formfield(**kwargs)
```